# Fastest pairwise distance implementation python/c++

Tags: python, c++, scipy, scikit-learn, pairwise

I am looking for the fastest implementation of pairwise distance between two sets of vectors (two 2D arrays) in c++/python.

**What have I done?** I ran the code from [here](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/08/memoryview-benchmarks/) on my server. In python, I found that the pairwise distance function from scikit learn and cdist from scipy.special.distance have fastest pairwise distance implementation.

**Question:**  Calculating pairwise distance is the major bottleneck of my program. Thus, I wanted to know if one compute pairwise distance faster if coded purely in C++ (given that a most of the underlying code in scikit-learn, scipy is in C++ )?

Comment: I am mainly looking for euclidian and manhattan distances. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems a bit broad. It is basically impossible to tell if a 2x speedup is possible because it requires the original implementation, benchmarking setup and hardware description. Since we have no information on any of those the chances of you getting a useful answer are very slim. Have you even checked if that algorithm is the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: @nwp: I have edited my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One fast way is to use an expansion of Euclidean distance that can be performed via matrix multiplication (from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236465/euclidean-distance-and-dot-product/2981910#2981910)):

> distance(X,Y)²=⟨X−Y,X−Y⟩=⟨X,X⟩+⟨Y,Y⟩−2⟨X,Y⟩

In numpy it can be performed like this:

```py
all_distances = np.sum(A**2, axis=1)[:, None] + np.sum(B**2, axis=1) - 2 * A @ B.T
```

The heavy lifting (`A @ B.T`) is done by heavily optimized matrix multiplication libraries that numpy uses under the hood.

Also see PyTorch's [`torch.cist`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cdist.html) function, with `compute_mode='use_mm_for_euclid_dist'`.